# Im trying to fit a custom function to some 1-D histogram data but I get - TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Tags: python-3.x, curve-fitting

Id like to fit a function to some data from a molecular dynamics simulation using the curve_fit function from Python 3. The raw data is a 40,000 row column specifying the end-to-end distance of an 11 residue polypeptide in water (btw). I want to fit a histogram of a subset of this data. This question is posted elsewhere on the forum and Ive tried to implement the ideas there but I havent been able to make it work. Here is the code and some output:

```
#take subset from 40000 frames
ppII_etoe_wt = np.take(etoedist_wt_np, loc_ppII_wt)
print(len(ppII_etoe_wt))
print(ppII_etoe_wt[:5])

1495
[[16.273 ]
 [27.0817]
 [30.5083]
 [26.2768]
 [17.6271]]

#make histogram bins and histograma 
binedges_1D = np.arange(4,33.01,0.2)
bincenters = 0.5*(binedges_1D[1:]+binedges_1D[:-1])  

ppII_etoe_wt_hist = np.histogram(ppII_etoe_wt, binedges_1D)

#fitting function
def fit_function(x, C, t):
    return C*(float(x**2)/(1-x**2)**9.0/2) * np.exp(-0.75*t/(1-x**2))

#convert histogram to numpy array
ppII_etoe_wt_hist = np.array(ppII_etoe_wt_hist[0])

print(np.shape(ppII_etoe_wt_hist))
print(type(ppII_etoe_wt_hist))
print(type(bincenters))
print(np.shape(bincenters))

(145,)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
(145,)

#attempt to fit function
popt = curve_fit(fit_function, bincenters, ppII_etoe_wt_hist)
print(popt)

TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalarsTh
```

Comment: If you could please link to a data subset that, for example, contains every 100th data point (400 points total) that would be very useful.